# why are some trigonometric substitutions not explained in books?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

In some books I find trigonometric substitution explained for only 3 cases
in which one is:

$$\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=acos\theta$$
but so far i've never seen this one
$$\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=asin\theta$$

I believe it's a legit substitution since  you can choice where to put the angle in the triangle. Why does nobody explain this one?

Comment: Probably because they expect you to be able to apply the second if you know how the first one works. (The latter does, in fact, crop up in computations; in particular, it shows up a lot in integration over spherical coordinates where it's more convenient than the former.)

Comment: Also, they want me to do $x=asin\theta$ and with that get the first substitution, why not only take the definition of cosine and multiply by the $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either one is fine. Perhaps $x=\sin\theta$ is the preferred substitution because the derivative is simple ($\text{d}x = \cos\theta\text{ d}\theta$), whereas for the other substitution the derivative will involve a negative sign.

Comment: I got a conclusion: 
Looks like those 3 substitutions i mentioned (which i didn't mention) cover all the posibilities for substitutions, also I'll invoke this answer: Looks like x=asinx is prefered because the derivative stuff.
For the other 3 substitutions im just guessing is the same reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a triangle whose vertices are (-a,0), (a,0) and (0,a), the first substitution is an intersection of between the sides of this triangle with horizontal lines from -a to a, the second substitution is an intersection if the sides of the triangle with vertical lines from 0 to a.